# Drawing RadioButton in DataGridColumn in specific point

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, radio-button, drawing

I wrote one `GridView` with custom column that it's editing control have four `RadioButton` in a square , after edit step I want to show the selected box checked and other unchecked , but I can't find any drawing function that draw radio button , is there any drawing function that draw RadioButton , please guide me ?
Editing Control :
[image: Editing Control]
Drawing after editing
[image: Drawing after editing]

Answer (score 2):

I found `RadioButton.cs` [source code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/RadioButton@cs/1/RadioButton@cs) that I think it will be helpful,though you can use this code that draws eclipse for `RadioButton`:

```
private void DrawEllipseRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   // Create pen.
   Pen greenPen = new Pen(Color.Green, 3);

   // Create rectangle for ellipse.
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);

   // Draw ellipse to screen.
   e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(greenPen, rect);
}
```

this will give you something like not checked `RadioButton`.

and this for checked `RadioButton`:

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(greenPen, rect);
```

examples from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cy2c290.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your answer but you can see in picutre 2 in question that i draw ellipse but i want draw radiobutton this means that i have shape 2 and my question is this that is there any drawing graphcs that draw radiobutton in one location if not my work is best otherwise i must change my drawing. i use this application for 3 years but this question remain in my mind without reponse.